# Create Cross Section in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, cross-section

I need to create a cross section and chart from it in Google Earth Engine. Here is an example that has been done using QGIS. Please find the image below -
[image: Cross section of a river dem]
How can I do that?

Comment: Why does it have to be GEE? What have you tried so far? What did googling yield?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
// add variables
var CrossSection = CrossSection; // draw a single lineString without corners
var numbPoints = 5000; // spacing in lat/lon between the sample points

// Get a point value along the line every ... meters
var point1 = ee.List(CrossSection1.coordinates().get(0));
var point2 = ee.List(CrossSection1.coordinates().get(1));
var XmapList = ee.List.sequence(point1.get(0), point2.get(0), null, numbPoints);
var YmapList = ee.List.sequence(point1.get(1), point2.get(1), null, numbPoints);

// Construct a feature collection with points equally spaced
var points = ee.FeatureCollection(XmapList.map(function(Xcoord){
  var Ycoord = YmapList.get(XmapList.indexOf(Xcoord));
  return ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([Xcoord, Ycoord]));
}));

// Calculate the elevation at every location
var DEMIMAGE = ee.Image('AHN/AHN2_05M_INT'); // load an image with elevation
var elevation = DEMIMAGE.reduceRegions(points, ee.Reducer.first(), 10);
print(ui.Chart.feature.byFeature(elevation));
```

Example script with to different DEMs: [Link script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/01394c15dcd965cd2aaff92830056094)